# Magento2.4.4 swagger

Tags: magento2.4.4, swagger, swaggerui

Installed fresh magento 2.4.4 version on server . When i added some categories and products unable to check the swagger URL for API's

I navigated to https://myip/swagger. It is giving 404 page not found error.

When i google for this error , In magento2.4.4 by default swagger is disabled in production mode. But i enabled developer mode in magento then also it is not useful

I am using bitnami magento image to up and run my magento instance. Can any body know how to enable swagger in magento 2.4.4 .

I verified etc/config.php file as well, The Magento_Swagger module is already enabled.

**Please help me on this.**

I am using this bitnami instance https://bitnami.com/stack/magento/cloud

Answer (score 4):

If you didn't change deploy mode for your instance, by default deploy mode is `default` (not `developer`)

You need to change mode to `developer` for Swagger

**How to display current mode (CLI)**

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

**How to change deploy mode (CLI)**

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

You can see logic in `\Magento\Swagger\Model\Config::isEnabled`

```php
namespace Magento\Swagger\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\State;
//...
class Config
{
    //...
    public function isEnabled(): bool
    {
        return $this->state->getMode() === State::MODE_DEVELOPER || $this->enabledInProduction;
    }
}
```

Also you can set force mode with di in your module

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Swagger\Model\Config">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="enabledInProduction" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: I tried to change the code to 

public function isEnabled(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

Still i am unable to access swagger. My magento mode is developer.

Comment: In this case i just can suggest to debug `\Magento\Swagger\Controller\Index\Index`. Double check if you have module enabled in `app/etc/config.php`. I don't see any other reasons.

Comment: `app/etc/config.php`  module is enabled but when i put die or exit in `Contoller/Index/Index` its still showing page not found.

Comment: Is there any issue with `http_cache_hosts` . in `env.php` presently it is pointed to `localhost` and port as `80`

Comment: comment `dispatch` method for disable and just add some into `execute`

Comment: I tried to remove `dispatch` as well still same issue.

Comment: Is this `memcached` or `varnish` issue?

Comment: I'm not familiar with bitnami and don't know about configuration, restrictions, etc. Try to setup the same code locally and check if swagger works. Did you try to use request  `/index.php/swagger`? Possible you have some issue with routing.

Comment: memcached  - isn't affect. Varnish can if you already have cached 404 in Varnish cache. You can use parameter like `/swagger?v=1` where 1 is random string each time for prevent to load cached result.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the issue. It is with bitnami

when i run the following command it worked for me

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart
```

Hope it helps for you